# Adding a new card to the DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to add a new card to the database.
I have a page in React that when a user fills the form and clicks "Next", a new user is created and added to the Database.
The next page is Business Information he needs to fill, but when he clicks on "Create Card" it doesn't do anything and the Database remains empty.

This is the code for my BusinessRegistrationPage.js:

````
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import SimpleRegistrationComp from "../components/simple-registration/SimpleRegistrationComp";
import CreateCardComp from '../components/my-cards/CreateCardComp';
import {useState} from 'react';
function  BusinessRegistrationPage () {
    const[isStep1,setIsStep1]= useState(true);
    return  <Container>
                 {isStep1&&   
                  <SimpleRegistrationComp clickHandler={registerUser} 
                                 text="Next" >
                    </SimpleRegistrationComp>
                    
                    }
                    {
                        !isStep1&& <CreateCardComp clickHandler={createCard} ></CreateCardComp>
                    }
           </Container>;

function  registerUser(data) {
    registerNewAccount(data,
        (data)=>{
          if(data._id){
                toast('Account Created Successfully');
                setIsStep1(false);
            }
            else
            {
                toast('Eror Acount was not created');
            }
        });
 }

   function  createCard() {
       alert('create card');
   }
}
export default BusinessRegistrationPage;```
````

Comment: where is `registerNewAccount` ? Also Check your netowork /console tab to trace errors

Comment: There's another file, FetchHelper.js:
```let baseUrl= "http://localhost:3000";

export function  registerNewAccount(data,callback) {

    let url = baseUrl+"/api/users";
    let obj=getConfigurationForPostRequest(data);

    fetch(url, obj)
    .then(x=>x.json())
    .then(x=>callback(x))
    .catch(x=>callback(x));
}
```